# Optimizing the Layout of Arbitrary Shapes in a Plane

Tags: optimization, graphics, np

I am trying to create an algorithm that can take a set of objects and organize them in a given area such that a box bounding all of the shapes is optimized (either by area used, or by maximizing the span along one of the dimensions, etc.). All of the shapes are closed and bounded.

The purpose of this is to try and minimize material waste from using a laser cutter. The shapes are generated in CAD and can read into this algorithm. The algorithm will then take arguments for the working area (effective laser cutting area) as well as the minimum separation between any two objects, then attempt to organize the objects within the specified dimensions while trying to minimize the area usage. Alternatively, the algorithm can also try to maximize the object locations along one axis while minimizing the span along the other dimension. This would be akin to cutting off a smaller workpiece to cut from.

Ideally, the algorithm would be able to make translations AND rotations, but rotations aren't necessary.

For example, [this Picture](http://i832.photobucket.com/albums/zz248/Silntsoldier/Example.jpg) depicts the required transformation.

It should work with an arbitrary, but small (<25) number of objects.

Lastly, I don't expect anyone to solve this for me, but I would appreciate help toward either finding an algorithm that can do this, or developing my own. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know to what extent you want to create said algorithm or how you want to implement it, But i know of a program called OptiNest that can do  what you ask. It organizes geometric shapes to optimize the layout and minimize waste on a plane, i think in an autocad format.

Comment: You'd better provide a link to the OptiNest program.